# How to plot a sinc function at arbitrary location

Tags: matlab

In matlab the sinc function can be used to generate sinc function. The example in the matlab shows how to get a sinc and peak is at zero. But in reality the sinc which is the Fourier Transform of rectangular window can be peak at any bin/location. Consider we have only one sinuoid and when we do FFT after zero padding the peak of the sinc  will be located at the frequency of the sinusoid, not at zero as shown in the matlab example. My question is how to generate a sinc function, peak at arbitrary location?

Comment: `sinc(x-a)` centres it at `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will plot `sinc(x-a)` where `a` is the arbitrary bin

```
%range of x
x = -10:0.01:10;
%arbitrary bin
a = 5;
%plot results
plot(x,sinc(x-a));
```